# Is it the right JSON facebook android sdk image post response

Tags: android, facebook, json

Is it the right response i had posted an image from facebook android sdk app.

```
D/Facebook-Example(25353): Response: {"pid":"100002384000781_493277","aid":"100002384000781_53368","owner":100002384000781,"src":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/404559_233627800060018_100002384000781_493277_315872294_s.jpg","src_big":"http:\/\/a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/404559_233627800060018_100002384000781_493277_315872294_n.jpg","src_small":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/404559_233627800060018_100002384000781_493277_315872294_t.jpg","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/photo.php?fbid=233627800060018&set=a.233615786727886.53368.100002384000781&type=1","caption":"","created":1329120507,"object_id":233627800060018}
```

Comment: In this link check all graph api http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=104032556342992%2Fphotos

Answer (score 0):

The response to an HTTP POST should only be the Photo Id.  What you are showing there appears to be a response to a GET request.  Can you monitor your network traffic and check to see what is being sent/received?